# Modern readable alternative to Cron Format

Tags: data-structures, cron, format, schema, schedule

Is there any modern (JSON, XML, etc...) readable alternative to the Cron Schedule Format? I understand that, for instance `0 0 12 1/1 * ? *` is very powerful and can cover a lot of special cases, but it cannot be read by someone, who has not worked with cron or a similar tool before.

I would like to use something like:

`<schedule>
  <weekly dayOfWeek="Monday"/>
  <monthly day="1" />
<schedule>`

But I do not want to reinvent the wheel, so is there any standard or quasi-standard out there?